# Large ordered family of set inclusions complete?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I'm not an expert on set theory, so this might be trivial:
Let $\dots \subseteq X_{\alpha} \subseteq X_{\alpha+1} \subseteq \dots$ be a chain of set inclusions, indexed by ordinals(!), s.t. $X_{\alpha}\subseteq X$ for all $\alpha$. Does there exist a supremum of this chain?

Comment: In fact, your sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: so its even a maximum! thx!

Comment: It is called the ascending chain condition if you'd like to look up more about it.

Comment: okay, thx, but $X_{\alpha}$ is not a partially ordered SET, right?

Comment: @BipolarMinds That's right, the individual $X_{\alpha}$ are just sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set sequence is eventually constant: we can find some ordinal $\gamma$ such that for all $\alpha>\gamma$, $A_\gamma = A_\alpha$.

Its easiest proof goes as follows: Assume that the sequence is not eventually constant. Without loss of generality, we can assume the sequence is strictly increasing, by removing sets identical to the previous ones in the sequence.
Fix a well-ordering $\prec$ over $A$ and take $a_\xi \in A_{\xi+1}-A_\xi$ be the $\prec$-minimum of $A_{\xi+1}-A_\xi$. We can see that, if $\xi\neq \eta$ then $a_\xi\neq a_\eta$ so $A$ contains a set equipotent to the class of all ordinals, which is impossible.

---

Above proof uses the well-ordering principle, but we can avoid it.
Assume to the contrary, that our sequence is not eventually constant. We can also assume that the sequence is strictly increasing. Let define $f$ from $A$ to the class of ordinals by stipulating
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\alpha&\text{if }x\in A_{\alpha+1}-A_\alpha \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Then $f$ is a surjection from $A$ to $\mathrm{Ord}$. However, we can prove that it is impossible. Mimicking the proof of the [Hartogs theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) provides the nonexistence of such $f$.

Comment: Actually you need the index of the next $A_{\cdot}$ set (beyond the range used so far) that adds a new element. If the $A_{\xi}$ chain has strict  inclusion everywhere then this isn't a worry, but given only $\subseteq$ the sequence can have successive identical elements.

Comment: @BrianO Thank you for pointing out the gap in my proof. I am going to fix this, though it is not a vast gap because we can just remove sets identical to previous one in our sequence.

Comment: It's not a big woe, no. Here, the sequence itself is a class not a set, so some approaches to trimming aren't available. So define, by a transfinite recursion proceeding in tandem with the transfinite inductive proof, a function $\nu\mapsto \xi_{\nu}$. At stage $\nu$, $\xi_{\nu}$ is least $\gamma \ge \sup_{i < \nu} \xi_i$ such that $A_{\gamma}$ is not a subset of $\bigcup_{i < \nu} A_{\xi_i}$.

Comment: I think it's worth to point out the following: Let $\mathcal I = \{ \alpha \mid A_\alpha \subsetneq A_\alpha+1 \}$ be the set of indexes for non-trivial inclusions and let $X = \bigcup_{\alpha < \operatorname{Ord}} A_\alpha$. Then $\mid I \mid = \mid X \mid $ and thus the order type of $I$ is strictly less than $\mid X \mid ^+$. It is a nice exercise to show that any order type below $\mid X \mid ^+$ can be realized.